# Firebase - get single element form database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I try getting value from specific item form database. But when I use solution from documentation, then I getting specific value but from all items.

Ionic 4
Firebase realtime database

Database structure:

```
https://.......com/projectName/bills/
-Lh-LgSqR1vSANRnA09G{
amount: xxx
name: xxx
}
-Lh-LhZachVgF7rnqW-1{
amount: xxx
name: xxx
}
-Lh-LiyC3ve4DrKmdTEj{
amount: xxx
name: xxx
}
```

```
  getKey(){
    var refKey = firebase.database().ref('bills');
    refKey.once('value', function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnap){
        var billKey = childSnap.key;
        console.log('Key 1 ' + billKey);

      });
    });
  }
```

And I getting this result:

```
Key 1 -Lh-LgSqR1vSANRnA09G
Key 1 -Lh-LhZachVgF7rnqW-1
Key 1 -Lh-LiyC3ve4DrKmdTEj
```

Keys are good, but for all items.

I want get only one key for clicked element, not keys for all items in my database.

**UPDATE:**

```html
<ion-item style="color: grey;" *ngFor='let bill of myService.bills' slot='start' lines='none' (click)='getKey()'>
<p>  {{bill.name}}:  {{ bill.amount}} zł  </p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: "I want get only one key for clicked element". How do you define the key you want to get? The last one of the thee ones? The first one? One with a specific name?

Comment: I want key from item which is clicked.

Comment: Ok, can you add the code which corresponds to the click? In other words, where do you click? On a button in a table that list all the bills??

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are looping and that's why you are retrieving all the keys and the items inside the keys. To solve your problem, you can do the following:

```
  getKey(){
    var refKey = firebase.database().ref('bills').child("-Lh-LgSqR1vSANRnA09G");
    refKey.once('value', function(snapshot){
        var amount = snapshot.val().amount;
        var name   = snapshot.val().name;
    });
  }
```

This will get the data related to key `"-Lh-LgSqR1vSANRnA09G"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the item that was clicked on along in your `(click)` handler:

```
<ion-item *ngFor='let bill of myService.bills' (click)='getKey(bill)'>
```

Then you can use the information from that item in your function:

```
getKey(bill){
  console.log(bill.name);
}
```

Now I'm not sure how you populate `bills`, since you didn't share that code. But in order to read the key from `bill`, you will need to ensure that the elements in `bills` contain that key when you read it from the database. So **if** you currently only use `snapshot.val()` or `valueChanges()`, you may need to change that to also use `snapshot.key` or use `docChanges()` instead.